# solution of differential equation takes huge time

Tags: matlab, performance, ode

Before  posting of actual code, let me show you that my computer's processor's and memory information is good:

[image]

Yesterday I have posted  about Lorenz equation(classical equation from chaos theory), where one of  great guy helped me and show  solution, here it is:

```
function f=lorenz(t,x,a,b,c)
        % solve differential equation like this
        %dx/dt=a*(y-x)
        %dy/dt=-x*z+b*x-y
        %dz/dt=xy-c*z/3
        f=zeros(3,1);% preallocate result
        f(1)=a*(x(2)-x(1));
        f(2)=-x(1)*x(3)+b*x(1)-x(2);
        f(3)=x(1)*x(2)-c*x(3)/3;
        end
```

and test program (script):

```
% test program
x0=[-2 -3.5 21];% initial  point
a=input(' enter first coefficient : ');
b=input(' enter second coefficient: ');
c=input(' enter third coefficient : ');
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) lorenz(t,x,a,b,c),[0 10],x0);
plot(t,x(:,1),'r'); 
title(' solution of x part');
grid on
```

But after running those lines

```
test_program
 enter first coefficient : 10
 enter second coefficient: 28
 enter third coefficient : -8
```

it is still running,  he said that  on his personal computer, it takes  2 second, so it is really  strange  what happens? Why it is not compiling on my PC? Even  as you saw it  My laptop has good parameters, please help me - even now it is running so I should cancel  using ctrl-c.

Comment: what i want to mention  that big interval [0 10] is reason for taking huge time

Comment: Same here, Windows 8 and Matlab 2015b. For `[0 8]` it takes 9.2 seconds, after that it "forever"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution for your conditions:
[image]

The problem in your case is that `ode45` starts to divide timestep and it became really small (`1e-5` and `1e-6`) at times after 6 sec - it made `29 388 481` iterations to achieve 10 sec!

So there are two important moments:

1. First of all it is not necessary to use `[0 10]` time interval. You can see at plot that you got solution much earlier.
2. Your method is coefficient-sensitive: I tried to use another values of coefficients `a`, `b` and `c` and it computes in few seconds.